# In interpolation, why does my choice of $x_0...x_n$ matter?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

This is more of a theoretical question regarding my choice of x's for my interpolation. I'm wondering if someone can explain to me why when I choose different x's for approximating a value at a point, I get completely wildly different answers. Take the following:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & \text{x} & \text{f(x)} & \text{f'(x)} \\
\hline
0 & 0.30 & 0.29552 & 0.95534 \\
1 & 0.32 & 0.31457 & 0.94924 \\
2 & 0.35 & 0.34290 & 0.93937
\end{array}
$$

Now I want to approximate, using Hermite Interpolation, the value at $H_4(0.34)$ (but this kind of logic applies to everything but spline interpolation I think, correct me if I'm wrong)

My initial guess was to just assume the x's in order, that is let

$$
 x_0 = 0.30
 ;x_1 = 0.32
 ;x_2 = 0.35
$$

This turned out to be wrong. The answer for this polynomial was wildly out of the acceptable range. It ended up that $H_4(0.34)=0.602832$ using this method.

Now, if you go back and you choose

$$
 x_0 = 0.35
 ;x_1 = 0.32
 ;x_2 = 0.30
$$

Then this gives a good approximation.

Why does this work? Can I choose any arbitrary x, or can I only use central/forward/backward difference methods?

If anyone could clear this up for me I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't made a mistake in calculating your interpolating polynomial?

Comment: @Rahul if you read what I said before that, I said it was wildly outside the acceptable range, which means it was completely wrong.

Comment: Yes, I read that. What I'm suggesting is that the answer you got that was "wildly outside the acceptable range" might not be the fault of the method but the result of a calculation error. I used a computer algebra software and obtained $$p(x)=-436.296 x^5+714.489 x^4-467.648 x^3+152.755 x^2-23.9277 x+1.62518,$$ giving the reasonable value of $p(0.34)=0.333489$ instead.

Comment: @Rahul, I have ran my work by my professor and my algebra and calculus clear. The problem is the selection of interpolation points. My professor suggested I do backwards difference, as suggested in my post, and it works. I would like to know *why* it works, which is what my professor failed to explain fully.